# Why AppleScript display dialog behaves so differently between Editor and Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

For instance, why this script works on **AppleScript Editor** but not **Automator**?

`display dialog "a lot of text                                      just to break to line 4                    whatever                                        continuing...                                       few more...                                                                           argh... there!" with title "just a test" buttons {"Cancel", "Uninstall", "Continue"} default button 3 with icon caution`

Commenting out everything after the *title* just on Automator, this is the difference I get:

[image]

I *want* the **title** and more than **3 lines** if possible, but those are not the only weird inconsistent behaviors I've seem in the past hour about applescript between **editor** and **automator**. The icon is another one.

In the instance, the error I get for trying it in Automator is this:

[image: Syntax Error]

Recording, questions here are:

1. Why? Why oh Apple, why?
2. Any way to at least make the ***title*** work?

Comment: It looks ugly in both of the dialog boxes you show. I don't understand the question...

Comment: @Cody it's ugly because it is *just a test*. maybe you would understand if you try to run the code... I'm not sure how to make it more clear.

Comment: I tried, but Visual Studio wouldn't compile it. I'm not in front of a Mac at the moment. I still don't think your question makes sense, though. So you've discovered Automator's behavior is at times inconsistent with AppleScript? That doesn't surprise me, given AppleScript came out a good 18 years ago, long before Automator. You're right that AppleScript doesn't support messageboxes with more than 3-4 lines. Figure out a way to say more by saying less.

Comment: @Cody Gray: you can make sense and immediately know the cause of the behavior if you know the inner workings of AppleScript :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that Automator imports the [terminologies of Applescript Studio](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Reference/StudioReference/sr10_panel_suite/sr_panel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20011224-ASKPanelSuite.Commands.DisplayDialog), which redefines redefines `display dialog` as part of the `Panel Suite`; that version doesn't have the `with title` parameter. You can check that by opening `Automator` using the Applescript editor. (Use File→Open Dictionary...)  I agree that this is a stupid decision by Apple :(

You can circumvent this problem by using

```
using terms from application "Finder"
    display dialog "a lot of text just to break to line 4 whatever continuing... few more... argh... there!" with title "just a test" buttons {"Cancel", "Uninstall", "Continue"} default button 3 with icon caution
end using terms from
```

from inside Automator; this tells Applescript's compiler to make the `display dialog` command call the standard definition.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've solved all my issues using Applescript Editor and saving the file as Application! :D  but your answer is flawless! ;)

Comment: I said flawless? I meant redefines redefines. :D